# Confusing behaviour when passing function name as action

Tags: c#, lambda, xamarin.android

I'm running code in an activity in a background thread. Why do the following two statements behave differently?

a)

```
RunOnUiThread (() => Toast.MakeText(this, "A toast", ToastLength.Short).Show ());
```

b)

```
RunOnUIThread (Toast.MakeText(this, "A toast", ToastLength.Short).Show);
```

The code in (b) throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

So it looks like (b) doesn't run on the UI thread, but why?

Comment: Understand the whole Lambda expression as the action in your first example. *Toast.MakeText(...)* is part of the lambda expression and thus invoked when the action representing this lambda expression is invoked. In your second example, the delegate/action is just the *Show* instance method -- hence, before passing it as argument to *RunOnUIThread*, the programm needs to evaluate/invoke *Toast.MakeText(...)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the second example first, because it's simpler.

So we have a method `RunOnUIThread`, and it accepts a delegate as it's parameter.  To run this line of code we first need to evaluate the first parameter's expression to a value, so we execute `Toast.MakeText(this, "A toast", ToastLength.Short).Show`.  This calls the `MakeText` method *immediately*, in the current thread (presumably a non-UI thread) in order to create an object of whatever type `MakeText` returns.  We then pass a delegate representing a call to the `Show` method of that created object to `RunOnUIThread` which takes that delegate and goes to run it on the UI thread.

Now that process doesn't actually run to completion.  As you're seeing, `MakeText` is throwing an exception because you're running it in a non-UI thread, so things are breaking.

The first snippet of code, when it goes to evaluate the first parameter's value, doesn't need to evaluate *anything* other than to say that there is a method (defined by the lambda) that executes `Toast.MakeText(this, "A toast", ToastLength.Short).Show()` when run.  It evaluates none of that code in order to create this delegate; it is all a part of the *body* of the delegate passed to `ShowOnUiThread` instead.  So it all runs in the UI thread, and things work fine.

Comment: Thanks @elgonzo and Servy for both your great explanations.